# I have shutdown problems on Ubuntu 22.10

Tags: nvidia, shutdown, hp, fan, 22.10

My HP laptop isn't shutting down correctly under Ubuntu 22.10.

The OS shuts down, and the screen also turns off, but the fan and the led indicator on network key remain on.

I need to press and hold the power button every time to completely turn everything off.  How can I fix that? I have a freshly installed Ubuntu on a 1TB hard drive.

Comment: I will give it a try thank you for your help

Comment: I wonder if this might be more of a bios / hardware problem … if the options in the comment don’t work, try a live usb session and see if you can shut down from that. If that doesn’t work either, suggests something outside the os is preventing shutdown.

Comment: From terminal, try **shutdown -h now**. If the same issue occurs, then try **shutdown -P now**. If either work, you can make a hot-key combination to save typing out a terminal command.

Comment: I have tried it stucks also on live usb please help this really freaks me out already